# Remove a database field when deleting property from a class using datamapper

Tags: migration, associations, sinatra, datamapper, field

I am using datamapper in a Sinatra application. I currently use the command

```
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

to handle the migrations. I had two Classes (Artists and Events) with a 'has_n' and 'belongs_to' association. An Event 'belonged_to' one Artist and an Artist could have many Events associated with it.

I changed the association to be a many_to_many relationship by deleting the previous parts of the class definition which governed the original one_to_many association in the models and adding

```
has n, :artists, :through => Resource
```

to the Event class and the corresponding code to the Artist class. When I make a new Event, an error is kicked off.

```
#<DataObjects::IntegrityError: events.artist_id may not be NULL
```

The :artist_id field is a relic of the original association between the two classes. The new many_to_many association is accessed by event.artists[i] (where 'i' is just an integer index going from 0 to the number of associated artists -1). Apparently the original association method between the Artist and Event classes is still there? My guess is the solution to this is to not just use the auto_upgrade method built into datamapper but rather to write an explicit migration. If there is a way to handle this type of change to a database and still have the auto_upgrade method work, that would be great!

If you need more details about my models or anything please ask and I'll gladly add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, DataMapper's `auto_upgrade` does not work very well -- or, to say the least, it doesn't work the way I expect it to. If you want to add a new column to your model, it will do what it should; try to do anything more sophisticated to a column and it probably won't behave as you expect.

For example, if you create a property of type `String`, it will initially have a length of 50 characters. If you notice that 50 characters is not enough to hold your string, adding `:length => 100` to the model won't be enough to make `auto_upgrade` change the column's width.

It seems you have stumbled upon another shortcoming, although one may argue that, in your case, maybe DataMapper's behavior isn't that bad (think of legacy databases). But the fact is that, when you changed the association, the `Event`'s `artist_id` column wasn't removed, and then when you try to save an `Event`, you'll get an error because the database says it is a required field.

Notice that the error you are getting is not a validation error: DataMapper thinks everything looks ok, but gets an error from the database when trying to save the object.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Auto-upgrade is not a shortcoming at all!  I think of auto-upgrade as a convenience feature of DataMapper.  It's only intended purpose is to add columns for you as far as I know.  So it is great for getting a project started quickly, and managing test and dev environments without having to write migrations, but not the best tool for making modifications to a mature, live project.

For that, DataMapper does have migrations!  Use the dm-migrations gem.  The shortcoming is that they are not very well documented... at all.  I'm actually working on changing a current project of mine over to using migrations, and I hope to contribute some instructions to the dm-migrations github wiki.  But if you aren't ready to switch to migrations, you can also just update columns manually using an SQL client, and then continue to use auto-upgrade for new columns.  That's what I have been doing for 2 years on my project :)

Comment: hah, yea I've also been deleting columns with navicat locally, but I definitely want to get migrations working properly for the app on heroku.